# Cannot Use Portcls.h Methods in Windows Driver Kit Visual Studio 2022

Tags: windows, audio, driver

I have started learning how to make drivers for Windows. I can make a simple driver that elevates the privelege of applications on Windows machines. Recently, I turned my attention to trying to develop an audio driver. I am trying to create a port using portcls.h as specified here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/subdevice-creation

However, there is constantly a linker error "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" whenever I try and use methods in portcls like "PcNewPort". I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2022 Community, reinstalling Windows SDK, and reinstalling Windows Driver Kit. I'm assuming I'm getting these errors because something isn't specified in the "Linker->Input" of my project.

The test driver I've written does use "#include <portcls.h>", and visual studio does recognize the class objects like "PPORT". It just doesn't know what the methods are.

Is there something else I should include in the properties of my project? Am I missing some weird include statement? I've attached a screenshot of my simple driver below: Thanks!

[Simple Audio Driver Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0RIV.png)

I tried manually including the path to the "portcls.lib" in "Linker->Input->AdditionalDependencies" as "$(DDK_LIB_PATH)portcls.lib", but that still does not fix the issue. I've tried searching online, but everything I've tried hasn't worked. All attempts lead to same "LNK2019" error.

EDIT:

I finally figured out the issue. The issue was two-fold. When specifying the additional libraries in "Properties->Linker->Input->AdditionalDependencies", you must specify the library as a complete path using back slashes. I had typed "$(DDK_LIB_PATH)portcls.lib" instead of "$(DDK_LIB_PATH)\portcls.lib". The reason I did not catch this is because I was copying the format from the "Inherited Values" section in AdditionalDependencies.

The other problem came when trying to use the "PcNewPort" method of portcls.h. If trying to create a Midi port, you have to include "dmusicks.h" with #include <dmusicks.h>. Also, you have to use the class ID "CLSID_PortDMus" as it is the same as specified in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/portcls/nf-portcls-pcnewport